# How can specify new value for default system enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have one question

How can I specify new value into system enum?

For example, the LoginFailureAction has a enum that define with microsoft in c# how can I get new value into this enum?

Comment: Well, it is _possible_ to pass around a value not defined in the enum by casting a value of the underlying type. (of course, things will probably fall apart if you actually try to use it in any of the existing APIs) Your best bet is to simply wrap/abstract your usage of the enumeration with your own custom enum/class that has the additional functionality you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can't change the default value of a type. The type is the type, and you can't change it.